# QGIS Project Variable as Integer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

I need to count how many times I executed a Pyhthon script in QGIS and I would like to do so by using a project variable as counter. However, I can only create them as string, thus I can't perform mathematical operations with them (count = count + 1).

Is it possible to change their type to integer or to create a counter using pygqis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prj = QgsProject.instance()
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(prj,'counter',"0")
counter=int(QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(prj).variable('counter'))
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(prj,'counter',counter+1)
```

The first line finds the current project (needed for QGIS >= 3). The next line initializes to zero, the last 2 lines read and set the counter incremented by one.

Comment: Written at same time as @Spacedman 's answer - he's focusing on the str/int conversion, the above adds the PyQGIS variable part.

Comment: It worked! Thank you.

Comment: I'd assumed the poster knew how to create string project variables, and I used an explicit `str` conversion instead of what I suspect is a coercion somewhere to string in your last line. But yay it works!

Answer (score 2):

Convert between strings and integers with `str` and `int`:

```
>>> x = "1"
>>> str(int(x) + 1)
'2'
>>>
```

So you'll be storing the string representation of your count as a string. Convert back to int when you retrieve it, and convert back to string when you store it.

Beware of errors if converting non-valid strings to ints:

```
>>> int("s")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's'
```

Comment: Actually I faced the error you mentioned, but @Houska answer helped me. Thank you for your time.